# VMware Delphi conflict

Tags: delphi, vmware

I don't know whether this is rightly a Delphi question or VMware question, but I'm seeing a persistent and very annoying conflict while using Delphi 10.2.3 on VMware Workstation Pro 16.2 in a Windows10 VM, and I'm hoping someone can shed some light.  Maybe there's a VMware setting that will clear this.

While working in Delphi, the IDE freezes for anywhere from 10 to 30 seconds or more, only when certain actions are performed.  The actions that cause the freeze are starting a compile/build, and (if Code Completion and Code Parameters are turned on) typing a period or left parenthesis while editing - there may be others that I haven't isolated.  The rest of the VM does not freeze, and CPU/disk usage does not change significantly in either the VM or the host OS while the IDE is frozen.  Once the freeze clears, the requested action completes normally.  I did not experience this under VMware 15, nor did it start happening when I first upgraded to 16 or when I installed any new software - it just started happening a couple months ago.  A different VM with Delphi XE2 does not exhibit the freeze.  I have two computers with VMware WS 16.2, one on a Win10 host and the other a Win11 host, and this VM exhibits the freeze on both hosts, so it would seem to be something in this particular VM.

The VM's C: disk is pretty shy on space, only 14Gb left on a 500Gb virtual disk.  (The host disk has tons of room, but I've tried expanding the drive in the VM config and always get an error.)  But it doesn't appear to be a swapping issue since disk activity on both host and VM doesn't change during the freeze.

As for RAD Studio, I only have Delphi Win32/64 personalities installed, with none of the other platforms.  EurekaLog is installed, which adds things to the IDE & compiler, but otherwise there are no IDE add-ons (Gexpert, etc.) installed, just a bunch of 3rd-party components.  And it's not project-specific, as even a brand new 1-empty-form project does the freeze.  Turning off Code Completion/Code Parameters at least lets me type without the freeze on every period or left paren, but using Ctrl-Space or Shift-Ctrl-Space to manually invoke those functions does cause the freeze.

Any ideas???  Thanks!

Comment: What is the amount of RAM dedicated to the VM? How many CPU core are allowed for the VM?

Comment: 20Gb mem and 4 cores.  The underlying hardware is an I9-10900 with 64Gb of mem for my primary development machine.  The second machine is a 11th-gen I7 with 32Gb mem.

Comment: 20GB and 4 cores are perfect. You said the VM disk still has 14GB free, that's more than enough. Did you check if any path the IDE, the project or Windows make use really exists? You said only Delphi is blocked, so you could run ProcessMonitor to see what the IDE (and LSP process) are doing.

Comment: I did have a couple old paths in the IDE search path and removed them, but that had no effect.  I'm digging into procmon now.

Comment: OK, I may have found it.  I had a network share defined that no longer exists but was still on the system path.  Procmon showed that bds.exe was trying to create a file in the C:\Windows\CSC\... folder that referenced that mapping name with a NAME NOT FOUND error when the freeze started.  Deleting the share and rebooting seems to have eliminated the freeze.  I'll continue to work with it to see if that really does clear the problem.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove invalid path from the IDE, project and system environment. Invalid path always take time, and may take huge time if this is a path involving a network share.

It take time for Delphi because the path are use to find modules required by the IDE.

To find out the invalid paths, use [Microsoft tool called ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). Using it you can see what is wrong with paths, files, registry keys and more.